# Problema em rodar app Flutter no emulador android no VS code

Tags: android, flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\rapha\OneDrive\�rea de Trabalho\Projetos\Dart\App - MyFrase\hello_world\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

The error is very clear, in your path you have a non-ascii character.

Move your flutter project into this path: `C:\Users\rapha` and run build and it'll work. This will apply to all your future projects. You can't have anything inside this folder or it's subfolders `�rea de Trabalho\`.